# Can only get either a long access token or a refresh token

Tags: react-native, auth0

I am using react-native-auth0 sdk. Here is how I use auth0 to do facebook login.

```
auth0
    .webAuth
    .authorize({
        scope: 'openid profile email offline_access', 
        //audience: config.auth0.audience,      //option (1)
        audience: auth0Domain+'/userinfo',      //option (2)
        responseType: 'token id_token',
    })
    .then(auth0Cred => {
        console.log("Auth0 Auth Result: "+JSON.stringify(auth0Cred));
        dispatch(signInAuth0Successful(auth0Cred));
        if (callback != null) {
            callback(auth0Cred);
        }

        dispatch(saveAuth0RefreshToken(auth0Cred.refreshToken));

        //return auth0Cred;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

For the audience there are two options for me.

When I use option (1), it gives me (the long version of) accessToken, idToken, scope, expiresIn, tokenType.

When I use option (2), it gives me (the opaque version of) accessToken, idToken, refreshToken, expiresIn, tokenType.

However, I need both the long accessToken and refreshToken at the same time? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation** - When you use an `audience` for your own API, you are opting in to receive a JWT Access Token (long token). If you only need to call the Auth0 `/userInfo` endpoint then the default behaviour is only to offer an opaque access token - this is expected behaviour (if somewhat confusing).

Out of interest, why would you require a JWT Access Token if you are not specifying your own audience?

However, to try and solve your request - please check if you have set your Client in the Auth0 Dashboard to `OIDC Conformant`. Under `Clients -> Your Client -> Settings - Advanced` (at bottom of page). Screen shot below:

[image]

If this doesn't work we can explore other options - so please leave a comment beneath if required.

With OIDC Conformance, you would not receive a Refresh Token for a *SPA* (implicit flow). Instead, use Silent Auth - see [reference docs here](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/refresh-tokens), so make sure you do have your Client Type set to `Native`.

*Based on OP feedback* - Check that the Resource Server also has `allow_offline_access` enabled. Can patch this with Management API. Alternatively, just go to your API in the Auth0 Dashboard and toggle the switch on the API settings page.

[image]

Comment: I will have a backend server which provide RESTful API. In this case, is that I should use option (1) for my audience? Currently, I am using localhost for my backend

Comment: I have set the OIDC Conformant, but I still cannot get the refreshToken

Comment: What is the suggested way to refresh the access token on client side?

Comment: See updates again. @ykn121 - if you want to DM in chat room let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally get the refresh token by enabling `Allow Offline Access` in the Management API.

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate the acknowledgement. let me add your final solution to the answer for benefit of others too. :)